# How can I get the first character in a string, even if it's an special/foreign character in PHP?

Tags: php

It is quite straight forward to return the first character from a string, e.g. by using `substr($mystring, 0, 1)`. However, if the first character in the string is a special and/or non-English character it will only extract the first byte from that character. Is there a function in PHP that manages extended characters as well in this case?

```
<?php
   echo substr("Above", 0, 1); // Will output "A"
   echo substr("Über",  0, 1); // Will NOT output "Ü"
?>
```

I have tried to find an answer at Stack Overflow, but didn't find any... I expect this has been asked before :)

Comment: Use [`mb_substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.mb-substr.php). https://3v4l.org/j3eLe

Comment: @Yoshi Perfect! I found the answer at the same time as your response! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ASCII characters, Unicode characters stores in 2-bytes so for Über you need to get 2 first bytes:

```
echo substr("Über",  0, 2); // Will output "Ü"
```

so you need to check characters encoding before using `substr`:

```
$str = "Über";
//$str = "About";
if(mb_detect_encoding($str) == "UTF-8")
    echo substr($str, 0, 2);
else
    echo substr($str, 0, 1);
```